# Google Data Studio incorrect calculated metrics

Tags: calculated-field, looker-studio

I am creating calculated metrics in Data Studio and I am having trouble with the results.

Metric 1 uses this formula:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN (  Event Category = "ABC" AND Event Action = "XXX" AND Event Label = "123" ) THEN ga clientId (user) ELSE " " END )
```

[[To count the events with distinct clientIds]]

Metric 2 uses this formula:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN (  Event Category = "ABC" AND Event Action = "YYY" AND Event Label = "456" ) THEN ga clientId (user) ELSE " " END )
```

[[To count the events with distinct clientIds]]

Metric 3 uses this formula:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN (  Event Category = "ABC" AND Event Action = "ZZZ" AND Event Label = "789" ) THEN userId(user) ELSE " " END )
```

[[To count the events with distinct userIds]]

The formulas work fine and when I do Metric 2/ Metric 1 the number is correct for a one day time span. When I do Metric 3/Metric 2 the number is wrong. Why is this? It doesn't make sense to me since they are both numerical values.

Also, when I increase the date range the Metric 2 / Metric 1 is incorrect too! Any ideas why these are not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are aggregating over a certain amount of data, then these calculations will not be exact; they will be approximations.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that Google Data Studio is more accurate with data properly loaded into BigQuery rather than data loaded through something else like a PostgreSQL connector. Otherwise, `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` may be used.